# LINQ: dictionary from string[]

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have to create a dictionary for use in a DropDownListFor based on absolute paths retrieved in a string[].
I want ot know if there's a way to have the key be just the folder name and the value be the full path?

Here's what I have so far:

```
// read available content folders from FTP upload root
var path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResearchArticleFTPUploadRoot"]);
var subfolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToDictionary(r => r, v => v);           
ViewBag.BodyFolderChoices = new SelectList(subfolders, "Key", "Key");
```

I tried:

```
var subfolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToDictionary(r => r, v => new { v.Substring(v.LastIndexOf("/"), v.Length-v.LastIndexOf("/"))});
```

Thinking that grab after the last "/" in the path for the folder name as the Key... doesn't work... Ideas?

Comment: They must be unique - these are sub-folders within a single folder

Comment: At least use Path.GetFileName to get the directory name.

Comment: @MarkJansen Don't you mean `Path.GetDirectoryName`?

Comment: I need both the full path and just the folder name. that way, the DDL shows the folder name, but the value is the full path.

Comment: @juharr: no, as that will get the parent folder name, it does the exact opposite as what is wanted.

Comment: @Beau: Getting a folder name in a decent way does not in any way prohibit you from also using the full folder name...

Comment: @MarkJansen You're better off using `DirectoryInfo.Name` as `Path.GetFileName(@"c:\someDir\");` would return an empty string instead of "someDir" because of the trailing directory separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DirectoryInfo` to do that:

```
var subfolders = Directory
    .GetDirectories(path)
    .ToDictionary(r => r, v => new DirectoryInfo(v).Name);
```

**EDIT**

I am aware that the `Key`-Properties will be the full path in this case. I did this to make sure you do not have to worry about duplicate keys when changing the operation to search for directories recursively:

```
var subfolders = Directory
    .GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .ToDictionary(r => r, v => new DirectoryInfo(v).Name);
```

which could cause issues if a folder two folders contain a equally named sub folder. If this is not a concern, you can switch the parameters of `ToDictionary`:

```
var subfolders = Directory
    .GetDirectories(path)
    .ToDictionary(v => new DirectoryInfo(v).Name, r => r);
```

Comment: You've got the parameters to ToDictionary in the wrong order.

Comment: i would do it that way, because if he somehow wants to get the directories recursivley, he could not be sure to not have duplicate keys.

Comment: @nozzleman: But that's not what the asker wants, nor what the given usage of `GetDirectories()` implies. Good on you for pointing it out, but we can only assume so much.

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate it. using this.

Comment: FYI, no recursion will be used here. This is for packaging up files/images/docs meant for 'Research Articles' into blobs for Azure storage. the research articles will have unique folders for each, one level deep.

Comment: In that case, you can also use the ToDictionary() with only a function as argument, it will call the function for the key, and will use the argument to the function as value.

`Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\tmp").ToDictionary(dir => Path.GetFileName(dir))`

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.IO; // to avoid quoting the namespace everywhere it's used

var subfolderPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
var dictionary = subfolderPath.ToDictionary(p => Path.GetFileName(p), p => p);
```

Note that `GetFileName` in this context will return the folder name if you give it a full path to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your method, the following works:

```
var subfolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToDictionary(r => r, v => v.Substring(v.LastIndexOf("\\")+1, v.Length - v.LastIndexOf("\\")-1));
```

Comment: The key is meant to be the folder name. You've got the parameters to ToDictionary the wrong way around.

Comment: I'll grant you that, but the full path is more unique than just a folder name, so logically that's backwards.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciate it